# How to join three subqueries and count the intersection correctly?

Tags: sql, mariadb

I would like to find out how many loyal users I have. The definition of that is that a user needs to have logged in at least once every rolling month.

> If the user has logged in once between 2018-08-21 and 2018-09-21  and
>   also once between 2018-09-21 and 2018-10-21  and also once between
>   2018-10-21 and 2018-11-21 then this is a loyal user.

I thought the best to achieve that is to join these three time defined subqueries. But I'm stuck with how to count it?  Each subquery shows a different count. Do I have to consider the lowest value as the intersection? Or am I doing it entirely wrong?

```
select p.country, round(SUM(a.GBytes+b.GBytes+c.GBytes), 2) as `Traffic`, a.Count, b.Count , c.Count
from (
    SELECT  username, 
            SUBSTRING_INDEX( callingstationid, '=', 1 ) as IP, 
            (SUM(`acctinputoctets`)+SUM(`acctoutputoctets`))/1000/1000/1000 as GBytes, 
            count(username) as Count
    FROM radacct
    WHERE (`acctstarttime` BETWEEN '2018-08-21 22:13:54.286223' AND '2018-09-21 22:13:54.286223')
    GROUP BY username
) a join (
    SELECT  username, 
            SUBSTRING_INDEX( callingstationid, '=', 1 ) as IP, 
            (SUM(`acctinputoctets`)+SUM(`acctoutputoctets`))/1000/1000/1000 as GBytes, 
            count(username) as Count
    FROM radacct
    WHERE (`acctstarttime` BETWEEN '2018-09-21 22:13:54.286223' AND '2018-10-21 22:13:54.286223')
    GROUP BY username
) b on a.username = b.username
join (
    SELECT  username, 
            SUBSTRING_INDEX( callingstationid, '=', 1 ) as IP, 
            (SUM(`acctinputoctets`)+SUM(`acctoutputoctets`))/1000/1000/1000 as GBytes, 
            count(username) as Count
    FROM radacct
    WHERE (`acctstarttime` BETWEEN '2018-10-21 22:13:54.286223' AND '2018-11-21 22:13:54.286223')
    GROUP BY username
) c on b.username = c.username
join cache_db.global_ip p on p.ip = a.IP
join cache_db.global_ip p2 on p2.ip = b.IP
join cache_db.global_ip p3 on p3.ip = c.IP
group by country;
```

**Result:**
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you only care if a user has logged in at least once per time period, there is no need to perform counts per user for each time period. Any user who has connected in the given time periods will appear in table `a`, `b` or `c` respectively and since you are `JOIN`ing them together on the `username` field, only users who have logged in in all three time periods will appear in the result set. Thus a simple `COUNT(*)` in your outer query (in place of `a.Count, b.Count , c.Count`) will give you the result you want.

If the same `username` can be used in different countries, then you will need to group by `username` and `country` in each of the subqueries and join on `username` and `country` as well.

Comment: Thanks, this is true but depending on which `country` field I pick, I get different countries: `select p3.country, ..., count(*)` vs `select p1.country, ..., count(*)` vs `select p.country, ..., count(*)`. This is somehow the same intersection problem. I get different countries for the same rows.

Comment: @Houman that would seem to imply that the same username can be used in different countries? In that case I think you would need to group by username and country in each of the subqueries and join on username and country as well.

Comment: That was exactly the problem. Thank you so much. I was working on this problem for so many days!!!